# How to find where form parameters are stored and use them in Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, requestjs

I am trying to scrape https://www.freelance.nl/opdrachten/zoeken for data using Request and Cheerio but I am running into issues posting search terms.

I cannot see where the search string and selected category are sent during the post when using the site and how I can use them in Request to automate searches from my node application.

Basically I want to be able to send different search terms using Request then I can scrape the returned html for the data I need.

So far I have this:

```
request.post('https://www.freelance.nl/opdrachten/zoeken', { form: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)

        }
    }
);
```

But as I cannot see where the form data is stored in dev tools, I cannot send the correct values in the 'form' object. I'm pretty sure it's in request payload, but how do I get to that from my node application?

Is there an easier way to do this? Am I completely wasting my time?

[image: Dev tools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Open your eyes ;) On the bottom of your image, look at **Request Payload**

```
projectFilterForm[keywords]
projectFilterForm[category][]
projectFilterForm[province][]
```

Update

```
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

require('request').debug = true;

var data = querystring.stringify({
    'projectFilterForm[keywords]': 'java'
});

var options = {
    followAllRedirects: true,
    uri: 'https://www.freelance.nl/opdrachten/zoeken',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'origin': 'https://www.freelance.nl',
        'referer': 'https://www.freelance.nl/opdrachten/zoeken',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36'
    }
};

var req = request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

I tried everything =)) Nothing... after redirect, we get default page. Maybe they use some session bases protection?

This is not node's problem. I tried to do this even in chrome's postman extension with no luck.

Comment: Yea I see this but I'm unsure how to get at this from my node app :(

Comment: To get it? You mean to "post" it by your node app? To emulate user's click to send form?

Comment: Yeah this, sorry lack of coffee and tired = poor explanations

Comment: Maybe they use some protection methods, because simple methods to get content after post data was send didn't work for me too. Even using postman.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm new to this kind of thing is there something I should be reading up on that would help? Or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 0):

I've slighly modified your code:

```
payload = {'projectFilterForm[keywords]':'javascript','projectFilterForm[category][]': '1'}
request.post('https://www.freelance.nl/opdrachten/zoeken', { data:payload },
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
}
```

);

Comment: It didn't help. Still gives me back the same html in the 'body' variable as if i hadn't entered any form data at all